# Try Neo4j’s Next-Gen Graph-Native Store Format and Docker initialization

Tags: docker, maven, neo4j, neo4j-block-store

I'm really excited to try out the new feature in Neo4j with the Block store format https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/neo4j-graph-native-store-format/

Currently, I have a question regarding my automated integration tests. I use Docker with the Docker Maven plugin. Is it possible to instruct Neo4j Docker to automatically create a database with a Block format (instead of the Record format)? If so, could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the format in as an environment variable like this:

--env NEO4J_db_format=block